# How to set the execution order of several scripts/functions?

Tags: matlab, execution

I have coded several scripts and I now want to program a MATLAB script that sets the execution order of the scripts. For example, my first script only includes the input variables that the second script requires for calculating certain outputs which are then transferred to a third function and these results are then plotted with the help of the fourth script. Now, my question is: How can I code a script to set the execution order so that I do not have to call each script beforehand?

Answer (score 2):

You should create a fourth script. This script will call all of the scripts in the order you put them there. Matlab interprets a script in the order they are programmed...

```
script2;
script1;
script3;
```